# Rails: Create an item that is associated to categories from categories edit page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

`items` will be called `keys` that just take in a name.

The reason I need the keys to be added via ajax on the categories edit view is because users can edit the category items display template. In the template it has keys they can use so when the items in the categories are displayed the value for that key that the item has will be displayed in place of the key name e.g. (key 'price' will display as $12).

Instead of the user creating keys on a different page then editing the template and realising they need to add more keys and switching between pages I decided having it on one page is better.

I haven't used a create action from a different view to its own controllers new.html.erb view and I'm fairly new to ajax. Here is what I got.

Category has many keys and key belongs to category

categories/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@guide, @category, @key_name], url: guide_category_path, remote: true) do |f| %>

   <%= f.label :name, "Key name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name, { :name => 'key_input' } %>

   <%= f.submit "Add"  %>
<% end %>

  <div>

   <%= form_for([@guide, @category], url: guide_category_path) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :name, "Category name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.label :template, "Template" %>    
   <%= f.text_area :template, { :id => 'edit' } %>

   <%= f.submit "Save"  %>

<% end %>
```

categories.coffee

```
jQuery ->
#just an editor plugin
          $('#edit').froalaEditor({
        toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', '|', 'color', 'emoticons', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', 'itemKey', '|', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', '-', 'insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'insertFile', 'insertTable', '|', 'quote', 'insertHR', 'undo', 'redo', 'clearFormatting', 'selectAll', 'html']
          })

#start of the ajax for the submit form
$('#new_category_item_key').submit (event) ->
  # If .required's value's length is zero
  if $('.required').val().length == 0
    # Usually show some kind of error message here
    alert 'New key added'
    # Prevent the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault()
  else
    $.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: $(#new_category_item_key).attr('action')
      data: string).success (json) ->
      alert 'New key added'
      return
  return
```

categories controller edit and update actions

```
    def edit
     @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
     @category = Category.friendly.find params[:id]
     @keys = CategoryItemKey.where(category_id: @category.id).pluck(:name)
     gon.keys = @keys

      @key_name      = @category.category_item_keys.new


    end

    def update
    @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
    @category = Category.friendly.find params[:id]

    if @category.update category_params
        redirect_to new_guide_category_item_path(@guide, @category)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
    @key_name      = @category.category_item_keys.new key_params

    end

    private

    def category_params

     if (current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) unless current_user.nil?)
        params.require(:category).permit(:name, :template)
        else
        params.require(:check_category).permit(:name, :template)
        end

    end

    def key_params

       params.require(:category_item_key).permit(:name)

    end
```

routes

```
resources :guides do
    resources :categories,    only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update] do
       resources :category_item_keys, path: "keys", only: [:update, :new, :create] do
          get :edit, on: :collection #-> url.com/guides/:guide_id/:category_id/keys/edit
       end
    end
end
```

When I submit the form to add a new key it takes me to the CategoryItemsController show action and throws a record not found error on one of the variables no idea why it even goes to this controller.

Comment: I think you should change `url: $(this).attr('action')` to `url: $('#form').attr('action')` because `this` is not the form in that scope.

Comment: Thanks i updated the question. it now takes me to CategoryItems Controller show action and throws a record not found error on one of the variables.

Comment: Is it a server-side error ?

Comment: Saying it cant find `@category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])` in the category items controller. But it shouldn't be in that controller in the first place

Comment: I cannot help you with RoR. Maybe the id you are passing is not in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In your form handler you want to block the default event no matter if the form is valid or not - since you don't want to submit the form normally in either case:

```
$('#form').submit (event) ->
   event.preventDefault()
   # ...
```

Returning false from the function your pass to `.submit` will achieve the same thing - jQuery will prevent the event from bubbling.

Also your validation is broken in a few ways.

```
$('.required').val().length == 0
```

Will only check the first element that matches the selector. Instead you would use a selector like so:

```
$(this).find('.required[value=""]').length == 0
```

Comment: On a side note - your routes are nested too deep. *Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.* Which is causing your forms, controller etc to be more complicated than they need to be. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources